# Unable to map åäö

Tags: vim, key-bindings, macvim

God kväll!

In my .vimrc I have:

```
imap <D-ä> <%=  %><left><left><left>
imap <D-ö> ()<left>
imap <D-u> ()<left>
```

The thing is, up until {I'm not sure when} I was able to use Cmd + ö to trigger inserting () and then stepping left one step.. but then it suddenly stopped working? All other mappings work as expected.
Both Cmd + ö and Cmd + ä stopped working.
I really don't have a clue what has changed in my system. -__-...

I've seen my share of posts and answers about "can't bind Ctrl", and some plugins overriding mappings, but when I do `:verbose map <D+ö>` and `:verbose map <D+ä>` I get nothing.  :\

## What would you look for?

Halmstrån:

- I've looked for clues and answers online (SO and vim wiki & ducking)
- I've restarted my computer
- source ~/.vimrc ...
- Removed "everything" from my .vimrc, and only added those three mappings - Cmd + u works, other two don't.

Yes my keyboard is set to Swe PRO and it's the same as it was when it was working. That's the messy wuuuut? for me - it used to work!

```
imap öö <ESC>
```

works just fine.

Comment: What shows up when you type `i<C-v>ä`? What does `:se enc?` say?

Comment: You should test: `:verbose map <D+ö>`, not `<C+ö>` given what you defined.

Comment: :se enc >>>  encoding=utf-8

Answer (score 0):

If this only occurs in `.tex` this could happen due to latex not really supporting special chars. For example `ä` should be `\"a`.

Comment: Nope, any textfile.

Comment: Which terminal emulator do you use, e.g. iTerm2, gnome-terminal,...?